# How to launch in Ubuntu 18 a program built in Ubuntu 20?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, glibc

I build my C++ program using gcc 10 in Ubuntu 20.04, and then run it in Ubuntu 18.04, but unfortunately get errors as follows:

```
/opt/aspen/my: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /opt/my/myRenderer.so)
/opt/my/my: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /opt/my/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
/opt/my/my: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /opt/my/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
```

Is it possible to fix this issue by installing some additional packages in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: There are some ways **1**. install `gcc`  on you current machine e.g. compile it from source. **2**. Upgrade the whole machine you have. **3** compile it on first machine into **static binary** file not dynamic one, then you can run it almost everywhere.

Comment: I see. And is it possible just to install missing glibc binaries in Ubuntu 18 (without compilation from sources)?

Comment: Yes - you can but it is not so easy and I did it once - you may end up having conflict between shared `libs`  on the machine you have - safest one is **static build** on Ubuntu 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways
**1**. install `gcc`  on your current machine e.g. compile it from source. It does not guarantee - since you may need to have a higher version of `glibc`
**2**. Upgrade the whole machine you have.
**3** compile it on first machine (Ubuntu 20) into **static binary** file not dynamic one, then you can run it almost everywhere.

Note. You may think of just compiling `glibc` on your machine - it is possible to do but since many others libraries are depended on `glibc` so may face errors for running CMDs or other programs. The safest one is option **3** static build.

Comment: @employed-russian I have used and using many statically build binary files on Ubuntu, Debian and Arch more then 5 years and I do not think so *Contrary to popular belief, static linking produces less, not more, portable executables on Linux.*